# Can I modify the VS code for better work with Python?

Tags: python, web-development, visual-studio-code

I would like to use Visual Studio code editor to be smoothly modified for Python code which I am learning right now for web development

Answer (score 1):

Open Python file and install suggested extension.

Or open extension menu, search Python and install one of available extensions.[image]